# Spring Batch Partitions + Threading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

If I use partitioning (let's say 10 partitions) and chunks in Spring Batch with a Task Executor like this

```
<task:executor id="partitionExecutor" pool-size="30" queue-capacity="50" />
```

on how many Threads will each partition run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each partition is run within it's own thread if you're using multi-threaded partitioning.  Granted, that doesn't stop you from doing other thread related things within the worker step...

Comment: so I can be sure that my reader for the partition will only ever read one chunk at the time?

Answer (score 0):

When spring batch uses a partitioning strategy, a thread will be used by each partition and it will execute the whole complete step. This avoids concurrency problems with respect to simple multithreading strategies